# How do I get checkbox as checked if value is stored in database?

Tags: php

I am  having a problem in retrieving checkboxes from the database. 
Actually I am making edit form by using the input form which insert the values in database. 
I am facing problem with checkboxes and other inputs works fine.

My code looks like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="proizvodi[]" value="0" <?if ($row['PROIZVODI'] == '0') $checked = 'checked="checked"'; ?> checked="checked"><b>product1<b/>                                    <input type="checkbox" name="proizvodi[]" value="1" <?if ($row['PROIZVODI'] == '1') $checked = 'checked="checked"'; ?> checked="checked"><b>product2<b/> <br/> 
<input type="checkbox" name="proizvodi[]" value="2" <?if ($row['PROIZVODI'] == '2') $checked = 'checked="checked"'; ?> checked="checked"><b>product3</b> <br/>
```

To make it more clear, I want only checkboes that are stored in db to be checked. for ex if value 1 is stored in db, product1 checkbox will be checked, if value 1 is no stored then check box will be not checked.

I appreciate any help or advice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do these textbox get generated? In php, or just hard coded in HTML?

Comment: the form is created in html and I am inserting these checkboxes in database by using implode function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? You need to echo the `'checked="checked"'` and do not assign it to a variable

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="proizvodi[]" value="0" <?php if (strpos($row['PROIZVODI'],'0') !== false) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>><b>product1<b/>                                    
    <input type="checkbox" name="proizvodi[]" value="1" <?php if (strpos($row['PROIZVODI'],'1') !== false) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>><b>product2<b/> <br/> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="proizvodi[]" value="2" <?php if (strpos($row['PROIZVODI'],'2') !== false) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>><b>product3</b> <br/>
```

Comment: @user3651819, What do you mean by not working? Error message? If this code is not working then there is something else on your code that does not work.

Comment: I mean when tried like you suggested, checkboxes still that are stored in db does not get checked. there is no chek mark in the box

Comment: @user3651819, if the db is from implode function, you should not use == in your if. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: How many checkboxes do you have? If it is 10 or more.. It is advisable to pad it with 0.. like 01,02,03 etc

Answer (score 0):

Write your rows like this don't make it any harder than it is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="proizvodi[]" value="0" <?php if ($row['PROIZVODI'] == '0') { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> /><b>product1<b/>
```